# Subform data not updating table

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, subform, adp

I am running MS Access 2010 as a front end to SQL Server Express 2008 R2 using an Access Data Project.

I have two tables: "Individuals" and "Researchers".

The "Individuals" table has primary key "Individual_ID". A foreign key in the "Researchers" table called "Researcher_ID" references "Individual_ID".

I created a form bound to the "Individuals" table and made it a Data Entry form. Then I added a subform control bound to the "Researchers" table, and using the subform wizard specified the one-to-many relationship from Individuals to Researchers.

I can enter data into the main form fine, and it populates the subform's "Researcher_ID" field in the subform with the "Individual_ID" from the main form. The entries are even saved within the subform.

The problem: The subform is not inserting new records into the "Researchers" table with the new records I create in the form and subform...even though it does insert new records into the "Individuals" table.

Comment: "The entries are even saved within the subform" can you clarify this? When you open the subform as a form, can you add records to the relevant table?

Comment: I can add records in the subform, but these records do not show up in the table "Researchers". Interestingly, when I use an unbound subform and manually link Individuals to Researchers, I can enter new records using the subform. I'd just use an unbound subform if I knew how to customize it edit the subform appearance.

Comment: Have you considered using lined tables rather than an adp? It is what is recommended with Access 2010. (BTW, you do not mention the behaviour of the subform when opened as a form.)

Comment: Please link to something where I can learn more about line tables

Comment: And the behavior is the same when the subform is opened as a form.

Comment: Oops Linked tables (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-importing-and-linking-data-and-database-objects-HP005241695.aspx) If the subform does not even work as a form, it suggests that there is something wrong with the record source. It might be worth trying to set up a new form based on the table and seee if that works.

Comment: Thanks. I also came up with a good command button solution using the form open prebuilt button as a template. Will do okay for these two forms, but. For others I will have to use w subform. As for not doing ADP, I'll look into it. But I don't really have much time to implement something totally different. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have primary keys? You can't write to any table without a primary key.